# Windows scheduler Groovy script

Tags: windows, groovy

how do I schedule groovy script to run hourly? I have groovy_home as C:\groovy and path I have %GROOVY_HOME%\bin. In task scheduler, the action start a program - "groovy C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\mPest\scripts\WeatherScript.groovy" What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `%GROOVY_HOME%\bin` on your `%PATH%`, you should just be able to tell it to run `groovy path\to\script.groovy`

Does that not work?

Comment: It doesn't work. I have groovy_home as C:\groovy and path I have %GROOVY_HOME%\bin. In task scheduler, the action start a program - "groovy C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\mPest\scripts\WeatherScript.groovy" What am I missing?

Comment: @user903772 Sorry for the delay in getting back to you...  Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do is set the Start in option as the folder that holds the Groovy script and I use the script name as an argument.

Additionally in my case, I am not one of the system administrators of the Windows instance, so I am not setting %GROOVY_HOME%\bin on my %PATH and am instead calling the full path to groovy.bat as the program/script. Can probably just use "groovy" if your path contains the path to your Groovy binary directory, but my answer will not contain it.

Full settings for the Action in Task Scheduler:
Program/script: F:\apache-groovy-binary-2.5.3\groovy-2.5.3\bin\groovy.bin (or just "groovy" or the full path to your Groovy binary folder)
Add arguments: *Name of your Groovy script* (not including .groovy)
Start in: *Path to folder where the groovy script is*